# Grid system resources for 1920*1080 grid

Tags: adobe-indesign, grids, layout

I just read this great book with extensive documentation of grid systems 
for print.

[image]

However I want to create a document that will be displayed on screen in landscape mode (1920*1080) but didn't find any resources regarding what kind of grid system to apply.

**Can someone tell me a good resource to learn or simply see example of grid systems displayed on screen?**

Comment: No I need to know how to create a grid that will be displayed on a screen in 16:9 (1920*1080)

Comment: Is it impossible to place some guides onto a master page. You should at first draw and tile some rectangles and then drag new guides to snap to them. Finally delete the rectangles. Impossible or useless due some apparent problem just in your works?